# How to output logs of cron in php fpm docker?

Tags: docker, cron, dockerfile

I have setup a cron inside a docker `php:8.1.0-fpm-buster`. It's running like expected, but there is no log showing up inside the docker desktop, it's a black screen.

Here is the docker file

```
FROM php:8.1.0-fpm-buster
ARG ENV

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron

RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
RUN chmod 777 /var/log/cron.log

COPY ./crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN /usr/bin/crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab

CMD [ "cron", "-f", "-L", "2" ]
```

What I was expecting inside the logs was something similar to linux logs of cron, like this example:

```
Jan 20 09:32:01 ns555555 CRON[21051]: (root) CMD (echo 'my command')
```

I tried differents commands:

- I added `bash -c` before the cron command
- I remove the `-L 2`

I have also found other stackoverflow posts, but eachtime it's not the same cron:

- [See cron output via docker logs, without using an extra file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395390/see-cron-output-via-docker-logs-without-using-an-extra-file)
- [Docker - Using PHP Cli base image for Cron container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47317399/docker-using-php-cli-base-image-for-cron-container)

What am I doing wrong ? Did I install the wrong cron ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution inside this post:
[How to run a cron job inside a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container)

I added `> /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2` after the command, now I have the command output inside the logs

```
* * * * * root echo hello > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2
```